# Convergence of Infinite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Using Mathematica, I have been able to make the following statement based on numerical evidence:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^i}{x^i}=\frac{x}{x-2}$$
for any $x≥3$. How can this be proven?

Comment: This is a geometric series.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370662/infinite-geometric-series-formula-derivation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $r = 2/x$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^i}{x^i} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i = \frac{1}{1-r} = \frac{x}{x-2}
\end{align*}$$
where the [summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) for geometric series is used.

Answer (score 1):

This can solved from scratch by taking one term out of the summation, changing the index range and refactoring to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
S=
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^i
&=
1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^i \\
&=
1+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{i+1} \\
&=
1+\frac{2}{x}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{i} \\
\end{align}$$

Now grouping the series terms yields
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^i
&=
1 \\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^i
&=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{x}}=\frac{x}{x-2} \\
\end{align}$$

where the sum converges for $\vert \frac{2}{x} \vert\lt 1$, not only $x \ge 3$.

Are you assuming positive integer $x$?