# How to show that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I remember that it equals 1, but I do not remember how to show the summation.

Comment: It is a geometric series, so you can approach the limit as $k\to \infty$ using the standard formula.  There are also many ways to derive the limit from "scratch".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Geometric Series Formula Derivation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370662/infinite-geometric-series-formula-derivation)

Comment: @hardmath This is not off topic

Comment: @Alephnull: My vote to close was based on the Question being a duplicate, consistent with my two Comments.  That said, the category "off topic" was used here (and in many cases) because a majority of those who voted to close selected the "missing context" subcategory.  The OP should have made the body of the Question a self-contained statement of the the problem for which help is wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the sum:
$$\sum_{k = 2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots$$
Note that this is a geometric sum with common ratio $r = \frac{1}{2}$.
We can factor out $\frac{1}{2}$ to get that:
$$\sum_{k = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots\right)$$
This part in the parenthesis is now in "standard form" (its initial term is $1$, and has some common ratio $r = \frac{1}{2}$).
So, we can apply the geometric sum formula:
$$1+r+r^2+\dots = \frac{1}{1-r},\quad\text{for }|r|<\frac{1}{2}$$
to get that:
$$\sum_{k = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots\right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1/2}{1/2} = 1$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof without words picture

[image: "proof without words" picture]
(Not sure how to make the picture smaller)

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: @Alephnull though your answer isn't as intuitive.

Comment: Also to be clear, this isn't original work. It's from https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/6d/6a/51/6d6a517c068ce16fd40e84e689c9cb53.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1/2 +1/2^2 +1/2^3 ... = 1/2 +1/2(1/2+1/2^2+...) . That is it is a solution to x=1/2+1/2 x and x=1.